# get radiobutton value checked or unchecked in jquery

Tags: jquery

Simple scenario:

```
<div class="question_wrapper">
    <input type="text" class="new_question">
    <input type="checkbox" class="radioinput" name="new_questionActive[]">
</div>
```

I am trying to figure out on how to get to the specific value of this radio-button, which is dynamically added everytime I press a button.

The JavaScript so far:

```
$('.new_question').each(function() {
    var active = $(this).parent().next(".radioinput").attr("checked") ? 1 : 0;
}
```

For some reason, it always yields "0" as value. I tried to work with `closest`, tried to workaround with `siblings`, with `next` .. but nothing seem to work.

**I need the very next `.radioinput`, which follows directly the prior `.new_question`.**

What am I missing or doing wrong?

**Update 1**

as suggested, I changed `attr` to `prop`, so it does look lie this now:

```
var active = $(this).parent().next(".radioinput").prop("checked") ? 1 : 0;
```

But still always `0`

Comment: change `attr("checked")` to `prop("checked");`

Comment: same effect, still always yields 0

Comment: Use `$(this).next().prop("checked") ? 1 : 0`

Comment: That might be because the property does not exist. Try it like this `var active = $(this).parent().next(".radioinput").is(":checked") ? 1 : 0;`
 or maybe `var active = $(this).parent().next(".radioinput:checked") ? 1 : 0;` The first one should work because it is an if clause condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `:checkbox` is sibling of current element so you need to use `.next()` with current element.

```js
var active = $(this).next(".radioinput").prop("checked") ? 1 : 0;
console.log(active)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="question_wrapper">
    <input type="text" class="new_question">
    <input type="checkbox" class="radioinput" name="new_questionActive[]">
</div>
```

OR, You can use [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to target descendant, instead of [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/)

```js
var active = $(this).parent().find(".radioinput").prop("checked") ? 1 : 0;
console.log(active)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="question_wrapper">
    <input type="text" class="new_question">
    <input type="checkbox" class="radioinput" name="new_questionActive[]">
</div>
```

Comment: That does indeed work. Thanks for claryfing! Thought I don't understand why moving to the parent and looking for `next` doesn't work. will accept this asap. Thank you good sir.